# How to use context variable in Watson conversation

Tags: node.js, socket.io, watson-conversation

I'm trying to develop a chat bot using node.js and socket.io,I can exchange the messages,but I can not enter in the conversation node ,could someone give me an example ?

Comment: Are you using the Watson Developer Cloud SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the watson conversation service is stateless,
advancing through your nodes requires your *Application* to store the `context` returned by `watson-conversation` and send it back no subsequent calls.

Check out this [blog](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/11/enhance-chatbot-conversation-context-variables-system-entities/)